# SSIS Getting PackagePassword error although all Passwords have been set correctly

Tags: ssis

I have a set of SSIS packages that I had run a few weeks ago. I've loaded it up to run the packages again, entered the password to access the solution and now the solution is failing with the error;

> Error 0xC001405E while executing package from project reference
> package "xxx.dtsx". The protection level of the package
> requires a password, but PackagePassword property is empty.

I have gone into all the packages, ensured that the ProtectionLevel is set properly and entered the password. I have also gone into any tasks that load up a package and re-entered the password. Lastly, I have gone into the solution properties and redone the password but it is still throwing the error.

Can anyone explain what is happening with it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing the password on specific package

First select the conflicting package, in your solution explorer

[image]

Then go to the properties of the package and go to the "Security" section.

Here you find both "PackagePassword" and "ProtectionLevel". These have to be set to the same settings as the Project.

[image]